# C# byteArray to Java

Tags: java, arrays, pointers, jna

I have a code in C# that calls methods from dll. Now what I want to achieve that in Java.

C#

```
[DllImport("dll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int FindNumber([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr, SizeConst = 64)] string atr, out IntPtr number);

[DllImport("dll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int GetData(int number, int dataId, byte[] dataBuffer, ref uint dataBufferSize);

int res=0;
IntPtr number=IntPtr.Zero;
res = FindNumber(null, out number);
uint dataBufferSize = 1024;
byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[dataBufferSize];

res = GetData(number, 6, dataBuffer, ref dataBufferSize);

Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataBuffer, 0, (int)dataBufferSize));
```

Java

```
LongByReference number = new LongByReference(0);
int res=0;
res = NativeInterface.FindNumber(null, number); 
IntByReference dataBufferSize = new IntByReference(1024);
Pointer dataBuffer = new Memory(1024);                                                                  
res = NativeInterface.GetData(number.getValue(), 6, dataBuffer, dataBufferSize);                            
if (res == 0) {                         
    byte buffer[] = dataBuffer.getByteArray(0, dataBufferSize.getValue());
    String bufferContent = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println(bufferContent);                              
}
```

If res is 0 it means that everything is Ok. After GetData() res is 0 but dataBufferSize is 1024, in C# is 8 and bufferContent=?;

If I do it like this

```
LongByReference number = new LongByReference(0);
int res=0;
res = NativeInterface.FindNumber(null, number); 
IntByReference dataBufferSize = new IntByReference(1024);
byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[dataBufferSize.getValue()];                                                                    
res = NativeInterface.GetData(number.getValue(), 6, dataBuffer, dataBufferSize);                            
if (res == 0) {     
    String bufferContent = new String(dataBuffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println(bufferContent);                              
}
```

res is 0, but bufferContent="",dataBufferSize is 1024  and dataBuffer is full of 0

Comment: is it an unsigned byte array that is coming from C#?

Comment: yes it is unsigned byte array

Comment: This is why you're having a problem.  Java signs its `byte`s, so you would have to subtract 128 from each of your bytes and then cast them into a `byte` before placing them in a `byte[]` within Java

Comment: Essentially the spectrum of values for a byte in Java is -128 - +128, instead of 0-255

Comment: Did you ever check the result of `FindNumber`? Can't really say much about this without a [mcve]

Comment: result of `FindNumber` is 0

Comment: Why are you searching for "null" in FindNumber?  What is it supposed to return?  Why is the C string you indicate not 8 bytes?  Is it a question mark and a semicolon or something else?

Comment: Your second syntax is simply wrong and won't work:  you cannot pass an array between Java and the native side.    The first syntax using `Memory` is more accurate.   Have you confirmed the values of the other parameters you are passing to GetData?

Comment: What are the native DLL's function declarations? Is the last parameter of `FindParameter` `int *` or `int **`?

Comment: I have only C# code and dll, I can not see functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works, I didn't include dll.lic in my project

```
    Pointer number;
    PointerByReference ref=new PointerByreference();
    int res=0;
    res = NativeInterface.FindNumber(null, ref); 
    number=ptr.getValue();
    IntByReference dataBufferSize = new IntByReference(1024);
    Pointer dataBuffer = new Memory(1024);                                                                  
    res = NativeInterface.GetData(number, 6, dataBuffer, dataBufferSize);                            
    if (res == 0) {                         
        byte buffer[] = dataBuffer.getByteArray(0, dataBufferSize.getValue());
        String bufferContent = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println(bufferContent);                              
    }
```